# Change NavigationBar Tint/Colour to different values for each ViewController in a Navigation Stack

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Ok, here's a weird problem I can't seem to figure out, and doesn't seem to addressed in any of the answers here, at least as far as *I can find...*

I have a Navigation Controller with 4 Push Segues into new ViewControllers. 
And I want to have the appearance of the Navigation Bar to be different colours for each View.

What I am seeing is that it is getting overridden on my first entry into a VC in the stack, and then I am unable to update it from then on.

In my Presenting VC I do this (to make the Nav Bar clear/invisible)

```
   [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Then in my pushed VC, I change the background color to a different color...

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundColor:bgColor];
```

When I press back to go into the presenting VC, the color from the pushed VC persists...

Any ideas ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh. Dumb mistake, but posting answer here for the community.

My NavBar code was in viewDidLoad, which of course never gets called again if it is the presenting ViewController in a NavigationController...

Moving the code to viewWillAppear fixed it.

breakpointsToTheRescue !

Comment: but it changes without animation.

Comment: I am cracking my head in this matter as well, any ideas on how to change the color along with your transition